# pandas nlargest lost one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
Id   query  count
001  abc    20
001  bcd    30
001  ccd   100
002  ace   13
002  ahhd   30
002  ahe    28
```

I want to find the Top2 query for each Id, based on the count. So I want to see:

```
Id   query  count
001  ccd    100
001  bcd    30
002  ahhd   30
002  ahe    28
```

I tried these two lines of code:

`df.groupby('Id')['count'].nlargest(2)`, the "query" column is lost in the result, which is not what I wanted. So how to keep query in my result.
Id     count

```
001     100
001     30
002     30
002     28
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of missing column(s):

```
df = df.set_index('query').groupby('Id')['count'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
print (df)
    Id query  count
0  001   ccd    100
1  001   bcd     30
2  002  ahhd     30
3  002   ahe     28
```

Comment: what does the "reset_index()" do at the end? thank you!

Comment: It create column from `MultiIndex`.

Comment: I see. So set_index as the otherwise missing column, then reverse the index to the original one?

Comment: Yes, it is solution if need nlargest.

Answer (score 2):

I use a `groupby` and `apply` the method `pd.DataFrame.nlargest`.  This differs from `pd.Series.nlargest` in that I have to specify a set of columns to consider when choosing my n rows.  This solution keeps the original index values that are attached to the rows, if that is at all important to the OP or end user.

```
df.groupby('Id', group_keys=False).apply(
    pd.DataFrame.nlargest, n=2, columns='count')

   Id query  count
2   1   ccd    100
1   1   bcd     30
4   2  ahhd     30
5   2   ahe     28
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with groupby still:

```
df.sort_values('count', ascending = False).groupby('Id').head(2)
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. Should be groupby Id at least

Comment: You're quite right.  It does then produce the output you're after though