# pandas groupby nlargest doesn't allow to see all the data set_index issue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to see 2-top values for each year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2006],'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'title':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f'], 'smth1':[6,6,4,5,6,4], 
'smth2':[9,8,7,6,5,2], 'smth3': [2,2,3,3,4,4]})
```

I use idea from here to prevent loosing cols: [pandas nlargest lost one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977640/pandas-nlargest-lost-one-column),

so this works perfectly for 1 or 2 cols added to set_index:

```
df_top = df.set_index('title').groupby('year')['value'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

However I want to see more data, and try:

```
df_top = df.set_index('title','smth1', 'smth2').groupby('year')['value'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

Thus, I have "level_1" col appearing right after the year column instead of 'smth1'.

In case I write:

```
df_top = df.set_index('title','smth1', 'smth2', 'smth3').groupby('year')['value'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

I got "**ValueError** For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type str."

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby('year').tail(2)
Out[148]: 
   year  value title  smth1  smth2  smth3
1  2018      2     b      6      8      2
2  2018      3     c      4      7      3
3  2017      4     d      5      6      3
4  2017      5     e      6      5      4
5  2006      6     f      4      2      4
```

Comment: Note, it works, but if  'year' col is not already sorted and one has 'year':[2016, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2006] instead, than  output is messy. So, need to sort it before, or after.